# Probability of getting a exact sum of 20 given a person has 5 coins in his pocket and the coins are of only 3 denominations 1,2 and 5.

Tags: probability

> A person has 5 coins in his pocket. In India coins are of only 3 denominations 1,2 and 5. He takes out coins in his pocket.What is the probability of getting an exact sum of 20?

My Approach in solving this problem:

Case1:1,1,2,2,5   p(1)=0   because 1+1+2+2+5 not equal to 20

Case2:1,2,2,5,5    p(2)=0  because 1+2+2+5+5 not equal to 20

Case3:1,1,2,5,5    p(3)=0  because 1+1+2+5+5 not equal to 20

In all the 3 cases the probability is 0. Hence, the answer is 0.

Is it correct?

Comment: Are those cases the only ones presented, or the ones that you came up with?  Note that instead of $3$ you should have $5$ in a couple places...

Comment: @abiessu ya only these cases are there.

Comment: Then your answer is correct as stated.

Comment: I think the question asks for the probability of being able to *make* 20 (to pay someone, e.g.) rather than having a *total* of 20, and cases should include ones like 1,5,5,5,5 else your answer is correct.

Comment: It is impossible to make a sum of exactly $20$ using exactly $5$ coins. The case analysis given is not sufficient for that. The question may be about making $20$ using some or all of the coins. If that is so, we need to make assumptions about the distribution of the coins. It is not at all clear what we should assume, but we could suppose the coins were put in the pocket independently one at a time, with each of the $3$ types equally likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x, y, z$ be the number of coins of value $1, 2,$, and $5$, respectively. Since the total is $20$, $$x + 2y + 5z = 20.\tag{1}$$ Since there are five coins, $$x + y + z = 5. \tag{2}$$

Subtracting four times (2) from the (1),
\begin{align*}
(x + 2y + 5z) - 4(x + y + z) &= 0 \\
z - 2y - 3x &= 0 \\
z &= 3x + 2y
\end{align*}
Then (2) becomes
$$
x + y + (3x + 2y) = 5 \\
4x + 3y = 5
$$
But it is clearly impossible to make $5$ with a nonnegative number of $4$s and $3$s.
In other words, this situation is impossible, so the probability is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If the probability of each coin is equal, the probability of totaling $20$ with all $5$ coins is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $\left(x+x^2+x^5\right)^5$ divided by $3^5$.
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x+x^2+x^5\right)^5
&=x^5+5x^6+10x^7+10x^8+10x^9+21x^{10}+30x^{11}\\
&+20x^{12}+15x^{13}+30x^{14}+30x^{15}+10x^{16}+10x^{17}\\
&+20x^{18}+10x^{19}+5x^{21}+5x^{22}+x^{25}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the probability is $0$ because there is no way to make $20$ with exactly $5$ of the given coins.